# Ktor client NoSuchMethodError

Tags: kotlin, gradle, telegram-bot, ktor

I want to write a telegram bot and use [this library from Github](https://github.com/kotlin-telegram-bot/kotlin-telegram-bot) for that. In this telegram bot I need to make some requests to another service, so I want to use the ktor client library for that. However when I try to instantiate the ktor `httpClient` I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.ktor.util.collections.ConcurrentMap.<init>(io.ktor.util.Lock, int, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIOEngine.<init>(CIOEngine.kt:32)
at io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIO.create(CIOCommon.kt:23)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientKt.HttpClient(HttpClient.kt:42)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientJvmKt.HttpClient(HttpClientJvm.kt:21)
at io.ktor.client.HttpClientJvmKt.HttpClient$default(HttpClientJvm.kt)
at problem.ktor.MainKt.main(Main.kt:9)
at problem.ktor.MainKt.main(Main.kt)
```

I made a new project and narrowed the problem down to the telegram bot library, which apparently conflicts with the kotr library. I assume some version conflict of the kotr library, because that's where the exception happens. **How can I solve the conflict?**

Here is a minimal reproducible example. Use the following build.gradle.kts file:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.30"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.5.2")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:1.5.2")
    implementation("com.github.kotlin-telegram-bot:kotlin-telegram-bot:6.0.4")
}
```

And run the following minimal main function:

```
import io.ktor.client.*

fun main() {
    HttpClient()
}
```

Maybe it's important, I use Java 15.0.2.

Comment: I've checked the build.gradle for the telegram bot library. I did not find any ktor dependency in it. In samples they are using ktor. In the webhook sample, they are using ktor netty 1.2.6. If we use that ktor version with your example, it works. Still there are some dependency warnings shown

Comment: @kaushik Using an old ktor version causes me other problems in my project. If the telegram bot library does not use ktor except for samples, do you know by chance why the problem happens when using the two libraries together (ktor and the telegram bot)?

Comment: Ktor and the telegram bot are using incompatible versions of kotlin run time. That may be the issue.

Comment: @kaushik How do you know which versions are incompatible? I see the library has kotlin v1.4.21 and I use v1.4.30, that doesn't seem to be such a big difference. I can't quite figure out the version of ktor. But by themselves both libraries work with my kotlin version, so is that some bug of v1.4.21?

Comment: The answer by Aleksei Tirman works. The telegram bot is shipping all of the samples along with the library. So the ktor 1.2.6 is also shipped with the library. Excluding it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problematic dependency is `com.github.kotlin-telegram-bot.kotlin-telegram-bot:webhook:6.0.4`. As a workaround you can exclude it since it's just a sample:

```
implementation("com.github.kotlin-telegram-bot:kotlin-telegram-bot:6.0.4") {
    exclude(module = "webhook")
}
```

Comment: Now only I checked, they are bundling all of the samples along with the actual library. I wonder why !